# Security questions about MySQL Databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a few questions about my MySQL Database.

1. Is it safe to just connect to the database via a PHP script in the start of my main HTML page? Like so:

   ```
   <?php

   session_start();

   $db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'acc', 'passwordexample', 'site') or die(mysql_error());

   ?>
   ```
2. On my site you can post anonymously. Is it safe to store the poster's IP as a value inside the database?

Comment: Yes and Yes. No problem with either. However `or die(mysql_error())` will not work, you're using `mysqli`, not `mysql`.

Comment: if I just call the php file in the html code cant users read that? and see what the password is?

Comment: No, people can't read what's in your PHP file. Your server parses the content of the file and only sends HTML to the browser. Try it for yourself, create the page and inspect it using your browsers debug tools.

Comment: That said, hardcoding your database username/password in the source isn't a good idea. If an attacker gets access to the code (though an improperly configured webserver, a traceback, etc), they could also get access to the database.

Comment: so where should I hold the private info?

Comment: You can create a constants file and put it in that then change the file permissions so that only the admin can read it. That's how I see it done most of the time.